# TCP retry in PHP sockets

Tags: sockets, tcp

I have a socket server that listens to connection on port 5001, when a connection is accepted and data is received i request my database to create a packet of data in a particular format and write it back to client.

To make the data transmission more reliable i have to implement a TCP retry in PHP, how do i go about this my current implementation uses a thread class that fires a thread to check and see if ack has been received for that packet till timeout else it retires 3 times till timeout, but havent hand any success with the same.

Is there a better way to implement the same.

Comment: If you can improve on TCP's reliability, then you're smarter than 99.99% of the people here.

Answer (score 2):

> To make the data transmission more
>   reliable i have to implement a TCP
>   retry in PHP

No you don't. TCP is already reliable and it already implements retry. And you don't have any way of knowing whether an ACK has been received or not so you can't implement what you described anyway. Unless you are talking about application-level ACKs? in which case you need to clarify your question.

Comment: Yes i got the question all wrong or probably have to rephrase the question. I basically use sockets for communication with a remote device, from my PHP portal. Now we have a protocol implemented which helps in the application communication level. Now when communication happens i have to implement an application level retry to see if i have received a response for a particular packet based on the protocol we have defined.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Better than what?